# CircleCI Tag Workflow Fails with "config file could not be located"

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

I'm running into a strange issue with a CircleCi workflow that is triggered by a tag. This CircleCi config actually works fine when creating and pushing a Git tag in one organization, but is failing in a new organization.
The issue seems limited to the tag workflow. Pushing to branches triggers `node/test` correctly.

When pushing a tag, this is the error that is displayed in the Circle pipeline:
[image: circleci failure message]

Here's the config.yml:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  artifactory: takescoop/artifactory@1.4.0
  node: circleci/node@5.2.0

jobs:
  publish:
    executor: node/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - artifactory/install
      - artifactory/configure
      - artifactory/npm-auth:
          scope: scope
      - run: npm publish

workflows:
  version: 2
  default:
    jobs:
      - node/test:
          context: artifactory
          filters:
             tags:
               only: /^v.*/
          run-command: lint
          setup:
            - artifactory/install
            - artifactory/configure
            - artifactory/npm-auth:
                scope: scope
      - publish:
          requires:
            - node/test
          context: artifactory
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^v.*/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
```

Can anyone help me understand if this is an issue with the CircleCI config file, or possibly with the organizational settings? Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!